# How to list files in perforce changelist without diffs?

Tags: perforce

```
p4 describe <changelist>
```

shows files in changelist with diffs. Is it possible to list just names of changed files using `p4` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p4 describe -s changelist
```

[p4 describe](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_describe_graph.html#p4_describe_(graph)) documentation:

> `-s` Display a shortened output that excludes the diffs of the files that were updated.